# How to place the "table" at the middle of the webpage?

Tags: css, html

I have a very basic Table structure to be placed in middle/center of the web page. I Have a code below, I know its incomplete to make this happen, as I am bad in structuring the HTML part, please help me

```
<div align="center" style="vertical-align:bottom">
<div align="center" style="vertical-align:bottom">
<table>
<tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Name</td><td>J W BUSH</td></tr>
<tr><td>Proficiency</td><td>PHP</td></tr>
<tr><td>COmpany</td><td>BLAH BLAH</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Also Please explain the concept behind the application of properties and CSS in achieving this time of structuring. so that I can use it in further learning....

I am completely newbie and dumb in HTML-CSS use... So I request you all the techies and Geeks to bear with my silly questions of HTML-CSS structuring.. Please dont leave the comments which demoralize me to go ahead with learning like "Is it a Homework..." or "GO TO TUTION CLASSES"etc...

Comment: Middle of page how? Horizontally, vertically or both?

Comment: Both, at center of the page equi distance in x and y axis

Comment: Please do not use tables for page layout.. If it is for tabular data then ignore, this comment.

Comment: @Eirinn It is basically for creating Login Page hence if not Tabular then how can i make it work with DIV structure?

Comment: Either I do not understand your question or you're misunderstanding what tables are... You can easily replace the tables with div and spans. Using tables for layout will almost always end in headaches :)

Comment: @Eirinn u are talking some thing etra about tables and divs, but I am interseting in this that how table can be replaced with DIV as you suggested

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The shortest and easiest answer is: you shouldn't vertically center things in webpages. HTML and CSS simply are not created with that in mind. They are text formatting languages, not user interface design languages.

That said, this is the best way I can think of. However, this will NOT WORK in Internet Explorer 7 and below!

```
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  #tableContainer-1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }
  #tableContainer-2 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
  }
  #myTable {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
</style>
<div id="tableContainer-1">
  <div id="tableContainer-2">
    <table id="myTable" border>
      <tr><td>Name</td><td>J W BUSH</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Proficiency</td><td>PHP</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Company</td><td>BLAH BLAH</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you explain how the table container-1,2 and mytable style is working here for div and table respectively?

Comment: But thats not displayed at the middle of the page as equidistant from top and asides its only at center from asides

Comment: This only does horizontal centering.

Comment: My bad; I forgot to set the HTML and BODY height to 100%. I updated the code. Does it work well now?

Comment: Yes It Does work Now, Now can you explain me how does these CSS work together here?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you don't understand? The 600 characters space here is not enough to give you a complete CSS course ;-) Oh, and don't forget to mark the answer that solved your question.

Comment: "HTML and CSS are not user interface design languages" what do you suggest I use if developing a user interface for a website ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky: either use a JavaScript-based layout framework like jQuery UI, or wait for CSS flexbox layout to become widely supported. Apart from that, there simply are no good solutions. We just have to make do with what we've got.

Comment: @Peter jquery-ui comes with an 32kb of css. I prefer bootstrap. My point is that CSS and HTML are user interface design languages.

Answer (score 10):

Try this :

```
<style type="text/css">
        .myTableStyle
        {
           position:absolute;
           top:50%;
           left:50%; 

            /*Alternatively you could use: */
           /*
              position: fixed;
               bottom: 50%;
               right: 50%;
           */


        }
    </style>
```

Comment: is that class to be applied on Table?

Comment: So easy, it's simple class : it say i want that my table to be placed at 50% on the top of page(that mean in the middle Vertical) and 50% on the left(middle of page horizantly).
please check the button Sloved.

Comment: What this does is that it puts the top-left corner of the table in the center of the page. So it's not really centering, but quite close.

Comment: I use 25%  to place near the center of page :)